# Set one hour event with date-fns and Angular 2/4 Calendar

Tags: angular, date-fns

So... I am having a bit of trouble setting a one hour event using date-fns and angular 4 calendar(https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar).

I can actually see the event scheduled on the month view and week view. The problem occurs when I use the day view, Sometime the event will display all day and other times it wont display at all.

Below is the code that I am using to set the event. Can someone shed a little light.

```
    {
  start : setHours(new Date('2017-06-07'), 1),
  end: new Date('2017-06-07'),
  title: 'FAKE APT',
  color: colors.red,
  actions: this.actions,
  resizable: {
    beforeStart: true,
    afterEnd: true
  },
  draggable: true
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the time using below line

```
setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 5),
```

Update 1:

To specify a particular date and time you should be using

```
events: CalendarEvent[] = [{
    title: 'No event end date',
    start: setHours(setMinutes(new Date(Date.parse("July 20 2017 02:00:00")), 0), 1),

  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/D5D53iYknWRnbOAnxYEo?p=preview)**

Comment: How do I specify if I want it to be July 4th, 2017 at 2pm for one hour? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. I can also do this if an end date needs to be there.

Comment: {
      start : setHours(setMinutes(new Date('2017-06-05'), 60), 12),
      end: setHours(new Date('2017-06-05'), 13),
      title: 'FAKE APT',
      color: colors.red,
      actions: this.actions,
      resizable: {
        beforeStart: true,
        afterEnd: true
      },
      draggable: true
    },

Comment: @jpavlov. Upvote the answer too. I will update you the end date in sometime i m working on it

Comment: So for the end date, i use setHours(the date I want), the hour the apt should end at). end: setHours(new Date('2017-06-05'), 13 -- Thanks I would still be stuck if it wasn't for your help!